# Update selected python interpreter from script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to update the selected python interpreter inside vs code from a script.

I tried:

- `.vscode/settings.json` in the workspace allows setting `python.defaultInterpreterPath` but it works only once. Even if select "default interpreter" in the UI (e.g. python 3.8), close vs code, change the setting to 3.9, open vscode again, vs code remembers 3.8.
- `$config_path/User/workspaceStorage/.../state.vscdb` also contains a key `ms-python.python` which got data for the selected interpreter `autoSelectedWorkspacePythonInterpreter` - but that does not even change when changing the interpreter in vscode (from the name of the setting that kind of makes sense)

Where does vs code even store the information which interpreter is selected by hand?

Any pointers welcome how to change the used python interpreter (preferable from a script running outsideof vs code, but I would also write a vs code extention if that is easier :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$config_path/User/globalStorage/.../state.vscdb`  --> `ms-python.python`.